# excel vba to return cell address using a string

Tags: excel, vba

i have make a table in excel from A1 to C6  where in column A i have string and in column B and C ihave number. Now i want to write a function code in vba in which when i pass a string from a column A i get the  range or cell address of column C corresponding to A. For eg if in A5 i have "apple" an when i pass apple as an argument to a function it should return cell address of C5 . I tried to search on net but not able to fin the code.

So guys please help me on this . this is very important.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some code examples, possible errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

The cell formula shown below will return the index in the array $A$1:$A$5 at which the value "peach" is found:

```
=MATCH("peach",$A$1:$A$5,0)
```

if the values in the array $A$1:$A$5 are:

> apple
>   pear
>   banana
>   peach
>   lemon

then the formula will return 4, the row-index in the array at which "peach" occurs. From this you should be able to complete your requirement.

Comment: thanks for your input an can pu please tell me how to store this in the form of  range.   i know

Comment: An EXCEL *Range* is simply the object created by referring to a contiguous block of cells by its upper-left and lower-right corners.

Comment: thanks for your input an can pu please tell me how to store this in the form of  range.   lets say i have a function call "returnString$(input As String)" when i call this function then C5 corresponing to A5 should be return by function and i can store that in a variable.